# PHP FTP directory listing fails with "ftp_nlist(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115)", but works in FTP client

Tags: php, ftp

I wrote this code for connecting to a FTP server with PHP. Connection ok, authentication ok but when I use `php_nlist` or `php_rawlist` the script loads indefinitely.
For passive mode I used command `ftp_pasv($conn_id, true)` and `ftp_raw($conn_id, 'PASV')` but the script don't work.

```
$ftp_server = 'xxx';
$ftp_user_name = 'xxx';
$ftp_user_pass = 'xxx';


$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server,21);
if ($conn_id)
{
    echo("Connected to FTP<br><br>");
}
else
{
    echo("Connection error<br>");
}
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
if ($login_result)
{
    echo("Successful authentication<br><br>");
}
else
{
    echo("authentication error<br><br>");
}

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die("Passive mode failed");


$list =  ftp_nlist($conn_id, "/");
foreach ($list as $file)
{
    echo ($file."<br>");
}
```

The error the I receive is:

> Warning: ftp_nlist(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115)

But I can login with my FTP client:

```
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Status: Connecting to 151.41.239.70:21...
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 220-You are user number 1 of 10 allowed.
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 220-Local time is now 19:07. Server port: 21.
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 220 You will be disconnected after 10 minutes of inactivity.
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Command: AUTH TLS
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 234 AUTH TLS OK.
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Status: Initializing TLS...
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Status: Verifying certificate...
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Status: TLS connection established.
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Command: USER nertobacos
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 331 User nertobacos OK. Password required
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Command: PASS ********
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Command: PBSZ 0
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 200 PBSZ=0
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Command: PROT P
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 200 Data protection level set to "private"
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Status: Logged in
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Command: PWD
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 257 "/" is your current location
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Command: TYPE I
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Command: PORT 192,168,1,108,195,143
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 200 PORT command successful
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Command: MLSD
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 150 Connecting to port 50063
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 226-Options: -a -l 
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Response: 226 4 matches total
2021-06-29 19:07:47 753 1 Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

Answer (score 0):

You are now using the active mode in FileZilla.

So do not switch to the passive mode in your PHP code. Remove this line:

```
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die("Passive mode failed");
```